# JQuery JSONP: One request multiple callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

The contents of my jsonp url http://host/dummyJsonp?callback=myFunction is:

```
myFunction("a");
myFunction("b");
myFunction("c");
```

but JQuery success function is called just once when I run this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://host/dummyJsonp",
    jsonp: "myFunction",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

Does JQuery supports multiple callbacks in one request?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't know exactly what your problem is. If you use the Deferred object, you can register multiple callbacks, but somehow I don't think that's what you wanted to know.

Comment: I expected success should be called 3 times where the parameter response is "a", "b" and then "c".

Comment: In that case, no, it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to call a callback multiple times with different arguments. Since the ajax call happens just once, there only is one response. That means you can not call multiple callbacks with different arguments.

If you want the response to be different, you have to make an ajax call three times and each time your server has to give you a different response.

The easiest workaround to achieve your desired result is to put all your responses on the serverside in a json object like this:

```
{
a:'a',
b:'b',
c:'c'
}
```

And in your success function you simply use the results you need:

```
success: function( response ) {
    console.log( response.a ); // server response
    console.log( response.b ); // server response
    console.log( response.c ); // server response
}
```

Comment: Hi @itd. There will be thousands of complex objects. I'd like to process them one by one and discard. I think making a single big object will cause memory leak.

Comment: One AJAX request can get back only one response so your options are either putting all objects into one big response object or using multiple AJAX requests and each time requesting the next set of data. If there will be thousands of complex objects I suggest the second option.